# problemas com dependências!

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tendo problemas com bibliotecas e estou tentando seguir essa dica abaixo mas não está funcionando:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607257/cannot-resolve-symbol-httpget-httpclient-httpresponce-in-android-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alterei o arquivo APP conforme link anexo mas as dependências continuam.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que fazer?

Comment: Está com aviso que vc ainda não sincronizou o Gradle. Faço o seguinte, altere de `compile` para `implementation` em seu arquivo do gradle, para as bibliotecas do apache, que vc inseriu e clique no **Sync Now**, localizado na parte superior da janela em azul. Veja se ocorre algum erro durante o build e insira o erro em sua pergunta! Caso contrário, confira se os imports aparecem para vc no código.

Comment: kkk, Erro de atenção: Coloquei a função (método), fora da classe. Só isso!
Obrigado!